# Add form items with javascript based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am building a recipe-database for myself (just to learn programming) and I've setup a base page with bootstrap, python, flask and sqlalchemy. I added the ingredients to the database and it is working fine. Now i can build recipes (another db.class) by adding these ingredients and combine them with the amount of them. I've prepared a form to setup all the required inputs.

For the ingredients i want to have a dropdown with all ingredients availabe in the db (done and working, see below). Now i want to add elements above in a container dynamically by selection of a dropdown-item. I staret by adding static elements first and it is working - when i use "onclick". This is what i have so far:

HTML of the dropdown:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Ingredient</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="amount"
    name="amount">
    </div>
    <label for="amount" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">g / ml</label>
    <div class="dropdown col-sm-2">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="Dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="addIngredient()">
        Choose Ingredient
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            {% for ingredient in ingredients %}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ ingredient.name }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript I am calling:

```
function addIngredient() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");

  var div_outer = document.createElement("div");
  div_outer.setAttribute("class","form-group row");
  container.appendChild(div_outer);

  var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.innerHTML = "Test";
  label.setAttribute("class","col-sm-2 col-form-label");
  div_outer.appendChild(label);

  var div_inner = document.createElement("div");
  div_inner.setAttribute("class","col-sm-2");
  div_outer.appendChild(div_inner);

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.innerHTML = "Amount";
  input.setAttribute("class","form-control");
  div_inner.appendChild(input);

  var label_unit = document.createElement("label");
  label_unit.innerHTML = "g (ml)";
  label_unit.setAttribute("class","col-sm-1 col-form-label");
  div_outer.appendChild(label_unit);

  var delete_btn = document.createElement("button");
  delete_btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  delete_btn.setAttribute("class", "close");
  delete_btn.setAttribute("onclick", "");
  div_outer.appendChild(delete_btn)

  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
  span.innerHTML = "&times;"
  delete_btn.appendChild(span)
}
```

As a first step i wanted to replace the text of "label" with the selection of the Dropdown with that:

```
//Getting Value
var selObj = document.getElementById("Dropdown");
var selValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
    
//Setting Value
label.innerHTML = selValue;
```

Question 1: But as soon as I change the event from "onclick" to "onchange" it stops working. Why?

Question 2: How can i make the created items identifiable with a unique id, so that i can use the label-text to identify the ingredient-id and add them to the recipe-class. How can i generate that id?

Unfortunately i dont now much Java or HTML yet but i try to learn :)

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry, i edited it, i hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 1:

The onchange attribute fires the moment when the **value** of the element is changed.

*Tip: This event is similar to the oninput event. The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus. The other difference is that the onchange event also works on  elements.*

So if you want the onchange to be fired you should consider creating a drop-down list using HTML `<select>` Tag.

## Question 2:

You can easily retrieve the id stored in your db of the item and set it in an attribute by your choice.

Comment: Thanks! Using the select forms, made it much easier! I misinterpreted the use of the dropdown elements and didnt know there are specific form-selects. Thanks!